# How to detect the silence at the end of an audio file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to detect silence at the end of an audio file.
I have made some progress with **ffmpeg** library. Here I used **silencedetect** to list all the silences in an audio file.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2> /home/aliakber/log.txt
```

Here is the output of the command:

**--With silence at the front and end of the audio file--**

```
[silencedetect @ 0x1043060] silence_start: 0.484979
[silencedetect @ 0x1043060] silence_end: 1.36898 | silence_duration: 0.884
[silencedetect @ 0x1043060] silence_start: 2.57298
[silencedetect @ 0x1043060] silence_end: 3.48098 | silence_duration: 0.908
[silencedetect @ 0x1043060] silence_start: 4.75698
size=N/A time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=N/A
```

**--Without silence at the front and end of the audio file--**

```
[silencedetect @ 0x106fd60] silence_start: 0.353333
[silencedetect @ 0x106fd60] silence_end: 1.25867 | silence_duration: 0.905333
[silencedetect @ 0x106fd60] silence_start: 2.46533
[silencedetect @ 0x106fd60] silence_end: 3.37067 | silence_duration: 0.905333
size=N/A time=00:00:04.61 bitrate=N/A
```

But I want something more flexible so that I can manipulate the output and do further task depending on the result.
I want to get the output something like **true** or **false**. If there is a certain period of silence exists at the end of the audio file it will return **true** and **false** otherwise.

Can someone suggest me an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure, that `ffmpeg` is the best software for *analyze*? What are you going to do next with the result? You can write simple script (maybe on bash) that will analyze ffmpeg output and will return *true* or *false*.

Comment: Also not clear what it means to "silence in the end." If at the end of the recording silent minute, and then at the very end - clicking the camera off button, if it is considered the silence?

Comment: Is there an upper limit on how much silence there may be at the end?

Comment: I have some audio recording of 2sec. I need to know if the recording is finished before user completes recording a sentence. If there is some silence at the end, I can assume that the sentence was finished.
So all I need to know if that the audio file is completed or not.
If there is silence for 0.05 sec i need false output and true otherwise.

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron I'm not very good with bash programming. That's why I need to find an easy way. As you suggested using ffmpeg output, I need to parse the output to return the true/false result. But I want something short to do the task.

Comment: @AliAkber Could you provide both examples of ffmpeg output with silence and without? I'll try to write short bash script.

Comment: I have edited the question @TarwirdurTuron

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -af silencedetect=n=-50dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 | grep -Eo "silence_(start|end)" | tail -n 1 | grep "start" | wc -l
```

**Output**:

- `1` - there is silence at the end
- `0` - there is no silence at the end

**Explanation**:
As I see in the *silence case* there is no `silence_end` at the end of log.

1. `2>&1` - redirect `stderr` to `stdin`
2. `grep -Eo "silence_(start|end)"` - filter log and keep only `silence_start` and `silence_end` from log. Each by new line.
3. `tail -n 1` - get last line. *(if it is. So now we there are 3 cases of state: `'silence_start'`, `'silence_end'`, `<empty>`)*
4. `grep "start"` - keep line only if it contains `start` *(2 cases: `'silence_start'`, `<empty>`)*
5. `wc -l` - get number of lines. *(`1` in `'silence_start'` and `0` in `<empty>` case)*

Comment: The OP says, "* If there is silence for 0.05 sec i need false output and true otherwise.*" - so, you'll need to parse the start time and the total time and subtract.

Comment: @Mulvya What is "silence"? :) See documentation for silencedetect: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-silencedetect . OP specified silence minimum duration in his command in post with `d` parameter.

Comment: Oops. Skipped over the use of `d`. Although it should be `0.05` then.

Comment: Thanks @TarwirdurTuron. It works. Can you please explain the code a little. Not sure what is happening behind the command :(

Comment: Thanks :) I'm using this solution for now.

Comment: No this doesn't work, because ffmpeg also splits out silence_end for the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @tarwirdur-turon doesn't work for me (in 2023 and ffmpeg version 5.1.2).

I came up with a somewhat convoluted script to do it. Convoluted, because it does error checking.

It uses 2 calls: ffprobe + ffmpeg to find reliably the duration of the audio file and tests it against the last `silence_end` by divison of the found values, which should be very close to 1.00. You can change the scale for calculating the division and various other values at the beginning of the script.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
set -e

INPUT="$1"
NOISE_FLOOR="-60db"
MIN_DUR=0.1
SCALE=2

[ -z "$INPUT" ] && echo "Needs audio file !" && exit 1

echo -n "$INPUT ends with silence: "

dur=$(ffprobe -i $INPUT -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" 2>&1)
if [ -z "$dur" ]; then
    echo "FALSE" && exit 1
fi

# xargs alone trims spaces
last_silence_end=$(ffmpeg -i $INPUT -af silencedetect=noise=$NOISE_FLOOR:d=$MIN_DUR -f null - 2>&1 | grep silence_end | tail -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 5)
if [ -z "$last_silence_end" ]; then
    echo "FALSE" && exit 0
fi

factor=$(bc <<<"scale=$SCALE; $dur / $last_silence_end")
if [ "$factor" == "1.00" ]; then
    echo "TRUE"
else
    echo "FALSE"
fi
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving Tarwirdur Turon's answer, now in 2024 it doesn't work for me, apparently the syntax changed a little bit

`ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.5 -f null - 2>&1 | grep "silence_end" | tail -n 1 | wc -l`

This command detect silence at the beginning or at the end, or in both.

**Output:**

**1 - there is silence**
**0 - there is no silence**