# How to detect delay or silence in an audio file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, audio-streaming, sox

I want to detect silence or delay in audio for a given duration file and remove it. For example, if someone started speaking and then paused for some duration to think.

There's this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507879/how-to-detect-the-silence-at-the-end-of-an-audio-file) but it only detects the silence at the end and doesn't remove it. My colleague suggested [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not sure if it's the best tool for the job nor how to use it frankly, moreover, the project died in 2015.

Comment: If you do this with ffmpeg alone, you need to call it twice: pass 1 to analyze audio with `silentdetect` and pass 2 to manipulate audio data (possibly with `aselect`) using the pass 1 stats. If you are expecting a lot of silent segments and are programming in binary data friendly language (e.g., Python) it could be easier to do the segment removal off FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sox` man page describes this in detail.

```
   silence [-l] above-periods [duration threshold[d|%]
          [below-periods duration threshold[d|%]]
```

if we start with a sample command:

```
sox input.mp3 out.mp3 -S silence -l 1 0.2 1% -1 0.2 1%

`-S`      - show progress
`silence` - the filter
`-l`      - leave x amount of each silence in tact
`1`       - trim from 1st silence [above-periods]
`0.2`     - amount of each silence to leave untouched [duration]
`1%`      - test for near absolute (0%) silence [threshold]
`-1`      - trim silence from the middle of the file [below-periods]
`0.2`     - amount of each silence to leave untouched [duration]
`1%`      - test for near absolute (0%) silence [threshold]
```

The detail courtesy of Sox:

```
   silence [-l] above-periods [duration threshold[d|%]
          [below-periods duration threshold[d|%]]

          Removes  silence  from  the beginning, middle, or end of the audio.  `Si‐
          lence' is determined by a specified threshold.

          The above-periods value is used to indicate if audio should be trimmed at
          the  beginning  of the audio. A value of zero indicates no silence should
          be trimmed from the beginning. When specifying a non-zero  above-periods,
          it trims audio up until it finds non-silence. Normally, when trimming si‐
          lence from beginning of audio the above-periods will be 1 but it  can  be
          increased  to  higher  values to trim all audio up to a specific count of
          non-silence periods. For example, if you had an audio file with two songs
          that each contained 2 seconds of silence before the song, you could spec‐
          ify an above-period of 2 to strip out both silence periods and the  first
          song.

          When  above-periods  is  non-zero,  you  must also specify a duration and
          threshold. duration indicates the amount of time that non-silence must be
          detected  before  it  stops  trimming  audio. By increasing the duration,
          burst of noise can be treated as silence and trimmed off.

          threshold is used to indicate what sample value you should treat  as  si‐
          lence.   For  digital  audio,  a  value  of  0  may be fine but for audio
          recorded from analog, you may wish to increase the value to  account  for
          background noise.

          When optionally trimming silence from the end of the audio, you specify a
          below-periods count.  In this case, below-period means to remove all  au‐
          dio  after  silence is detected.  Normally, this will be a value 1 of but
          it can be increased to skip over periods of silence that are wanted.  For
          example, if you have a song with 2 seconds of silence in the middle and 2
          second at the end, you could set below-period to a value  of  2  to  skip
          over the silence in the middle of the audio.

          For below-periods, duration specifies a period of silence that must exist
          before audio is not copied any more.  By specifying  a  higher  duration,
          silence  that  is  wanted  can be left in the audio.  For example, if you
          have a song with an expected 1 second of silence in the middle and 2 sec‐
          onds of silence at the end, a duration of 2 seconds could be used to skip
          over the middle silence.

          Unfortunately, you must know the length of the silence at the end of your
          audio  file to trim off silence reliably.  A workaround is to use the si‐
          lence effect in combination with the reverse effect.  By first  reversing
          the  audio, you can use the above-periods to reliably trim all audio from
          what looks like the front of the file.  Then reverse the  file  again  to
          get back to normal.

          To remove silence from the middle of a file, specify a below-periods that
          is negative.  This value is then treated as a positive value and is  also
          used  to  indicate that the effect should restart processing as specified
          by the above-periods, making it suitable for removing periods of  silence
          in the middle of the audio.
          The  option  -l  indicates  that  below-periods  duration length of audio
          should be left intact at the beginning of each period  of  silence.   For
          example,  if you want to remove long pauses between words but do not want
          to remove the pauses completely.

          duration is a time specification with the peculiarity that a bare  number
          is interpreted as a sample count, not as a number of seconds.  For speci‐
          fying seconds, either use the t suffix (as in `2t') or  specify  minutes,
          too (as in `0:02').

          threshold  numbers  may  be  suffixed  with d to indicate the value is in
          decibels, or % to indicate a percentage of maximum value  of  the  sample
          value (0% specifies pure digital silence).
```

Finally, a python sample code, to enable monitoring of the output:

```
try:
    self.comm = Popen(['sox', self.orig_file, self.new_file, '-S', 'silence',\
                       '-l', '1', '0.1', '1%', '-1', str(self.secs.GetValue()), '1%'],\
                       stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
    ......
```

It's worth pointing out that `ffmpeg` has the filters `silencedetect` and `silenceremove`.
While I do use `silencedetect` e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -stats -i interview.wav -af silencedetect=noise=0dB:d=3 -vn -sn -dn -f null -
```

`silenceremove` e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v quiet -i interview.wav -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=2:stop_threshold=-3dB -vn -sn -dn -f wav - | ffplay -hide_banner -v quiet -autoexit -i -
```

I've found to be less dependable.

It should also be pointed out, that `silence` is notoriously difficult to pin down, except on an individual/ad-hoc basis, due to background noise.

Comment: ended up using https://github.com/DarkTrick/python-video-silence-cutter

accepting this answer to close the question